# Bitbucket Git and Coda 2 branches

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, coda

I've setup a site in Coda as well as a repository in BitBucket and having problems with branches. I can push and pull, commit, add all of that in coda and it works. THe only thing that doesn't make sense to me is the branches. If I add a branch in coda and push changes to it, it does not show up in bitbucket, and same goes creating the branch on bitbucket and it doesn't show up in coda. How do I go about getting the branches to show correctly? Is there something I can do, even in terminal, that will update the branches locally and remote?

Answer (score 0):

The "git push" command pushes the master branch by default. If you want to push another branch, try:

```
git push origin some_branch
```

Comment: So basically you can't do remote stuff in coda